# A TextView with multicolored text

Tags: android, textview

How can I get a TextView to show text in more than one color? I'm looking for an effect like:

```
<span style="color:green;">Question: </span><span> Who was the first president?</span>
```

I can't use separate TextViews inside a Horizontal Linear Layout since it doesn't display correctly when the text wraps. I also tried using Html.FromHtml but it didn't work since it doesn't support styles on a span tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I also tried using Html.FromHtml but it didn't work since it doesn't support styles on a span tag.

No, but it does support `<font color="...">`.

Or, use a `SpannableString` to assemble the string yourself, applying `ForegroundColorSpan` styles for the appropriate sections.

Or, use a `WebView`.

Comment: Thanks. I like the Spannable idea. It just feels more appropriate.