# Is it possible to have single text view with two text colors?

Tags: android, textview

i want to have a single text view for 
not registered? create an account
i want not registered to be in black color and create an account in white.
is it possible?
I have tried with using two different text views to use two colors for text view but i need this to be in a single text view with two text colors in it.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/34954935/115145

Comment: String text = "<font color=#000000>Not Registered</font> <font color=#ffffff>Create an Account</font>";
        tvTest.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));